# Exception: Failed to retrieve form data. Please wait and try again

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I intended to write a script for

1. Changing uploaded file name
2. Changing file upload folder.

As I am new to Apps Script, I decided to do up 2 separate scripts to test and merge when both are working. I have since gotten both scripts to work as intended but suddenly the auto trigger for on form submit is not working. Throwing the following error.

> Exception: Failed to retrieve form data. Please wait and try again.

When I manually run the scripts, it is still working so I assume my coding is correct. I came across an article stating that adding

```
var form=FormApp.getActiveForm();
```

will help but it doesn't for my case.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question? You can see [ask] for guidance

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Google takes a bit longer to have formdata available. You could try

```
Utilities.sleep(1000);
```

or even longer if it's not time-critical and then try to get the response again.